# Java Spring boot application code execution

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

In my Java spring boot applications  i've many controller file. I'm hitting one endpoint in browser. In this req will send to the 8th controller file.How application Identify this

I'm having n no.of controllers in my project. I'm calling one endpoint ,In which flow my code will execute ? directly jumb to respective controller? or will serach from all controller file and respective one will execute ?